# How can follow this this guide to construct a graph with matrix/reachability

Tags: graphs, graph-traversal, dag, matrix, matrix-multiplication

Let's we have k matrices. For example we have 3 now,  where first one is 8x5  ($a_1$ x $b_1$), second one is 5 x 6 ($a_2$ x $b_2$) and last one is 6 x 8 ($a_3$ x $b_3$). And our goal is to figure out if possible to multiply within any given matrices and reach a matrix of dimension **x** and **y**, when **x** and **y** is given ahead of time. In this example, (8x5) x (5x6) x (6x8), end up a 8x8 matrix.   The hints is given, but I cannot visualize. Any more help is appreciated. can understand the first step, but have not idea about the second one.

> First, we can define nodes in the graph as the values of each $a_i$
> and each $b_i$, and put an edge from $a_i$ to $b_i$.
>
> Second, Whenever there is a chain of matrices $M_{i1},...M_{ik}$, we
> can multiply, then **x**=$a_{i1}$ has an edge to $b_{i1} =a_{i2}$, and
> $a_{i2}$ has an edge to $b_{i2}$ =$a_{i3}$, and so on, up until
> $b_{ik}$ =**y**. So there could be a path from **x** to **y** in this
> graph.
>
> Third, Inversely, for any path from x to y, the edges form a chain of
> matrices that we can multiply, which create a **x** x **y** matrix.
> therefore, **x** is reachable from **y** in the graph iff there is a
> chain of matrices which from the **x** x **y** matrix.

The first step create something like this ?

```
>  x--> 
> n8-->n5
> n5-->n6 
> n6-->n8
>   -->y
```

What is $M_{i1}$, $a_{i1}$ and $b_{i1}$? How does that differ to $a_{1}$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay let's say you got $n$ matrices $M_1,M_2,...,M_n$ with dimensions $a_1\times b_1,...,a_n\times b_n$.
Now we look at what happens to the dimension when we multiply two matrices $M_i, M_j, i\neq j$:
$$(a_i\times b_i)(a_j\times b_j) = a_i \times b_j$$
Notice that you can only multiply the two matrices iff $b_i = a_j = p$:
$$(a_i\times p)(p\times b_j) = a_i \times b_j$$
You might spot the pattern here: only the first dimension of the first matrix and the last dimension of the last matrix matter. Thus in order to get a matrix with dimensions $(x\ times y)$ you need a chain of matrices looking like that:
$$(x \times e_1)(e_1 \times e_2)(e_2 \times e_3)...(e_n\times y) = (x\times y)$$
where $e_i$ are just arbitrary numbers. This looks similar to a path in a graph, where you are walking from the node labeled with x to a node labeled with y.
Notice that for every node in the graph if it represents the first component of the dimension ($a_i$) of a matrix $M_i$ it's connected to the second component of the dimension ($b_i$).
Meaning $a_i$ and $b_i$ are connected. Secondly the second component of a dimension $b_i$ of a matrix $M_i$ is connected to all first components $a_j, i\neq j$ that have the same value ($b_i = a_j$). Now if  there is a path from $x$ to $y$ in a graph you can build an equation as shown above.

The graph in your particular example looks like this:

```
8(a1) -> 5(b1)
5(b1) -> 5(a2)
5(a2) -> 6(b2)
6(b2) -> 6(a3)
6(a3) -> 8(b3)
```

Now $8 = a_1 = x$ is your starting point and $8 = b_3 = y$ is your end point.

EDIT: Construction algorithm:

```
Input: arrays a,b with n elements
Output: adjacency list A of size 2*n
A = new array of 2*n lists
for i = 1 to n: A[i].add(i+n)
for i = 1 to n:
   for j = 1 to n:
      if b[i] == a[j]:
          A[i+n].add(j)
```

Notice that $A[i\leq n]$ corresponds to the node for $a_i$ and $A[n+i\leq 2n]$ corresponds to the node for $b_{i}$. Now if you want to check if you can build a matrix with a certain dimension $(x,y)$ you search through $a$ to find $i$ such that $a[i] = x$ and start a dfs or bfs from node $i$ which has the neighbors $A[i]$ and you stop your search when you arrive at node $n+j$ such that $b[j] == y$.

Comment: but how can/do we actually construct the graph systemically?  The given example is a bit "simple", since we know that if we are given x=8 and y =8, the chain of matrix can end up 8x8.  ok 8 / s=$a_{1}$, why not s= $a_{i1}$ ? got some understand and confusion of the subscript .

Comment: ahhh wait i think i know why you are confused about the subscripts...
you didn't use double subscripts.. instead of $a_{i1}$ it should be $a_{i_1}$ right?
This double subscript means the following: imagine you have some indices $1,2,...,j $ that address some objects $o_1,o_2,...$ and now you want to have a subset of those: $i_1,i_2,...,i_m \in \{1,2,...,j\}$ which address the objects $o_{i_1}, o_{i_2},...$.
Double subscripts can be confusing...

Comment: The important thing to realize is that the $i$ in $a_i$ is completely different from $a_{i_j}$. And that $i_1,i_2,i_2,...\in\{1,2,3,...,n\}$are a so called index family.  The tasks statement is indeed confusing.